# Node js - problem with query inside a loop

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I got a problem with my query for inserting value in MySql, to add member to an intervention.

It works fine for a few run and after got "ER_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT" and must reboot node js server.

I think the problem is my for loop , maybe i'm not using things properly.

Can someone help me figuring it out ?

```
app.post('/addmember', (request, response) => isLoggedin(request, settings => {
    let indicatif, time, distance, intervention, req;
    let length = request.body.data.length;
    intervention = request.body.id;

    req = "delete from participants where intervention = ? ;";
    connection.query(req, [intervention], (error, rows) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        for (x in request.body.data) {
            indicatif = request.body.data[x].username;
            time = request.body.data[x].time;
            distance = request.body.data[x].distance;

            req = "INSERT INTO participants set indicatif = ?, intervention = ? , time = ?, distance =?;";
            connection.query(req, [indicatif, intervention, time, distance], (error, rows) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }

        req = "update interventions set nb_participants = ? where id = ? ;";
        connection.query(req, [taille, intervention], (error, rows) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });

    response.end();

}));
```